# Unit test is failing because mock data created in constructors differs from raw mock data

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I'm just starting to learn unit testing and I have written the following test

```
const EXEPECTED: MergedFood = {
    id: '1',
    name: 'test mergedFood',
    ingredients: {
        '2': {
            foodID: '2'
        }
    }
}
describe('addIngredientToMergedFood()', () => {
    it('should add an ingredient to a mergedFood', () => {
        const mergedFood: MergedFood = new MergedFood('1', 'test mergedFood');
        const ingredient: Ingredient = new Ingredient('2')
        const result: MergedFood = addIngredientToMergedFood(ingredient, mergedFood);
        expect(result).toEqual(EXEPECTED);
    })
})
```

This is failing and I'm getting the following failure error:

> Expected MergedFood({ id: '1', name: 'test mergedFood', ingredients: Object({ 2: Ingredient({ foodID: '2' }) }) }) to equal Object({ id: '1', name: 'test mergedFood', ingredients: Object({ 2: Object({ foodID: '2' }) }) })

As I hope you can easily see, the values and structure are equal, but the `result` has a `MergedFood` and `Ingredient` wrapper (I assume because they were created via constructor).

So my question is, **how is this situation typically handled?** Is it common to mock out all data rather than by using constructors (seems like a lot of work) OR is there a way to strip the wrappers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
expect(JSON.stringify(result)).toEqual(JSON.stringify(EXPECTED));
```

You should probably use an array of ingredients in MergedFood, [{}] instead of {{}}. Otherwise your class contains a property named '2'. And not forget the semicolons (e.g. describe(...)**;** or = new Ingredient('2')**;**